# check all data, count them, sort by count and return one of each data bt mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that contains some data like below:

**Id**  : 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

**data**: 3,2,3,2,5,3,2,3,5,1

And I want this **output: 3,2,5,1**

This means that MySQL check all data, count them, sort by count and return one of each data.

I try @mysql_query `('SELECT * FROM`datatable`GROUP BY data');`

But it returns an unsorted group data and I have repeated data like 3333222551

Comment: 1 More question: how I can use this in pagination? i mean show 5 result in the first query and show 5 more result in second query without duplicated!!!

Answer (score 2):

Note: I included `data` in the `ORDER BY` clause so that you get a deterministic order in case of a tie in counts:

```
SELECT `data`
FROM `datatable` 
GROUP BY `data`
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, `data`
```